# Delete directory on network shared folder

Tags: vb.net, network-share, delete-directory

This question is bring from another forum which not having answer yet for my situation.

I have something to do on network shared folder. But when I search on Internet, it giving me a code to do in own computer only. Step that I want to do is:

1. Check destination (network shared folder) path is empty or not.
2. Delete folder content (not the main one) eg: "\USER-PC\File\"; the folder "File" no need to deleted, but the content inside is need to deleted.
3. Copy folder content from source to new destination.

No. 1 and 3 is OK. But No. 2 is not yet found. How to delete a content from directory on Network Shared Folder?

Delete directory code that I use but exception "Could not complete operation since directory is a root directory":

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(strDestination, FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
```

Please assist

EDITED:

To delete all files inside the main directory:-

```
Dim directory As New DirectoryInfo(strDestination)

For Each file As FileInfo In directory.GetFiles()
       file.Delete()
Next file
```

To delete all folders inside the main directory:-

```
For Each folder As DirectoryInfo In directory.GetDirectories()
       folder.Delete(True)
Next folder
```

Comment: What is the value of `strDestination` when you're getting the Exception?

Comment: strDestination value is: "\USER-PC\File\"

Comment: `\\USER-PC\File\` represents a UNC Share, which is a "root" and so cannot be directly deleted, you can only delete its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead (it's C#, you'll need to convert it to VB.NET):

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("\\USER-PC\File");
foreach(FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles()) {
    file.Delete();
}
```

Comment: Hey dai, thanks for your help, I was able to delete the directory..edited, combine from your given code to delete file and folders